# Variable strings of a url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are several different cities to scrap through

```
www.domain.ru/moskva
www.domain.ru/sanktpeterburg
www.domain.ru/yekaterinburg
```

How do I iterate operations with every of this domain without writing the entire url?
How do I make a variable?
i = moskva, sanktpeterburg, yekaterinburg
for i:

https://www.domain.ru + i?

How to make the code to process(scrap) all three websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in ["moskva","sanktpeterburg","yekaterinburg"]:
    process("https://www.domain.ru/"+i)
```

You'll want to change `process` to the actual name of the function.

Comment: Thank you.Will that iterate and go: moskva then sanktpeterburg then yekateriburg? How the iteration will be done?

Comment: Yes, it will do it in order.

Comment: Do you by a chance how to use IF with beatiful soup. I mean, let beautifulsoup look for some tag on webpage - if found (last page of results) - stop the program

Comment: I don't really know much about beautifulsoup, sorry. You may want to ask that as another question, if you can't already find someone else who's asked.